# When I launch an executable using " -console" in command prompt, second command prompt is launched. How do I pass control to another command prompt?

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I am trying to automate the installation process in Windows

```
import subprocess
import os
from pywinauto.application import Application
os.system('cmd.exe')

os.chdir('C:/PathOfExecutableIWantToLaunch')
os.system('ExecutableFile -console')
# A new command prompt is launched with options 1 and 2
# How to pass control to second command prompt
os.system('1')
# I want to pass option 1 to proceed with installation
```

How do I automate this part in Python?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve... If a command is started in a new console window, its standard streams are set to the console, so you will have to find the window handle and send keystrokes there at low level windows API. Why cannot you simply use the `subprocess` module to start `ExecutableFile`?

Comment: Hi Serge
I have tried using subprocess as well
    
    `subprocess.call('executable -console', shell = True)
After this commad a new cmd prompt is launched, where I am not able to proceed further without completing the setup with arguments '1' and '2'`.

Actually I am pretty new to this, so not clear on how to proceed

Comment: My question was more *is it an option to use `subprocess.call('executable', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`* and to explicitely manage the input and output of the subprocess?